# Brand new self-built machine in boot loop

Tags: boot

I have recently built a new machine to use it as a CUDA server, with the following specs:

PSU: Corsair CP-9020094-UK RM1000x 1000 W

Motherboard: Aorus Z390 AORUS PRO

CPU: Intel i5I-9600

RAM: Crucial 32 GB DDR4 2666 MT/s

GPU: NVidia Titan X HDD: Samsung 860 EVO 1 TB SATA 2.5" Internal SSD

I had bought pieces at different times and this computer has never started properly. At the beginning, I thought it was due to lack of ram and/or gpu. However, now everything is placed in there and simply does not work.

The computer starts, but does not boot. In the sense that, after a few seconds, it switches off and restarts automatically again, going in a never-ending boot loop.

I have googled this issue, but could not find a proper answer. I read that it could be a problem of the motherboard. For that reason, I asked for a replacement. But, the new one still has the same issue and I don't know what else I could do.

Comment: Does it boot loop during POST, or will it load UEFI, not find an OS, then boot loop? Can you access the UEFI firmware settings?  Have you ran the built-in hardware diagnostics _(accessed either via the UEFI firmware settings or via the UEFI boot options screen)_? Have you tried removing the GPU, disconnecting the HDD SATA cable, and all RAM DIMMs but one, then reseat the remaining RAM DIMM and try booting?  _If the answer is yes to the last part of the first question, it's likely an improperly configured UEFI and/or Secure Boot option for the OS you're trying to boot from and install._

Comment: It happens during POST. I have never seen anything appearing in the screen and I have tried disconneting all the unecessary components (e.g., gpu and hard drive). Nothing boot

Comment: If it doesn't complete POST, there's an electrical failure, as it's detecting a hardware fault and powering off to protect the hardware.  Is the CMOS battery inserted correctly _(some boards fail POST w/o one installed)_? I'd start w/ the basics, working up from there: disconnect all hardware & cables to the motherboard, plug back in the appropriate PSU connectors and power button leads, insert a new CR2032 CMOS battery, connect a monitor, and try to boot.  If it loads UEFI _(If it doesn't, read manual/contact Aorus)_, power it off, connect hardware one by one, starting with RAM, try to boot.